# How to configure root include path for dockerized php with nginx?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I trie to resolve the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/include/DB_tools.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/') in /var/www/html/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3
```

when I serve my `index.php` file.

This is line 3 in my `index.php` where the error occurs:

```
require_once('/include/DB_tools.php');
```

The files structure:

```
var
└── www
    └── html
        ├── include
        │   └── DB_tools.php
        └── index.php
```

In other words it try to configure the include root path for php files in a docker + nginx + php-fpm environment.

I've tried to set `chroot` and `chdir` in `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` inside my php-fpm docker image as follows:

```
chroot = /var/www/html/
chdir = /
```

and it gave me "File not found" error.

I also tried to set

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=/var/www/html/";
```

in nginx `default.conf` without success.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php-fpm
  php-fpm:
    image: php:8-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

My nginx config file:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Can you help me how to configure the root include path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I didn't find a recommended solution for that problem. So I decided to use another approach - just mount the `include` folder as a root dir by configuring it in the `docker-compose`'s file. Probably not the best solution, but defenitely the most simple and clear one.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php-fpm
  php-fpm:
    image: php:8-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./src/include:/include
```